# @> operator output not expected result?

Tags: postgresql, operator-keyword

I currently trying to understand why the `@>` gives me false when I evaluate this query

```
select tsrange('1990-01-01 01:00:00','infinity') @> tsrange('1990-01-01 00:00:00','2001-10-01 00:00:00')
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2e5b7e2b24ea8c0bda74f7cdae1c3d4

As I understand the operator from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html

It should answer whether the

> Does the first range contain the second?

In which case I would mean yes?

It seems to work in when I change the lower limit, but why should I change that?
it should still contain the second? or am I missing something

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for "overlaps" (`&&`), not "contains" (`@>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result is correct it must be `false`. Range Right operand is starting at `1990-01-01 00:00:00` but Left Operand is starting at `1990-01-01 01:00:00` which is one hour after the left operand. That's why it is returning `false`. with `@>` operator range of right operand must be with in the range of left operand.(both boundaries are included)

if you compare like below it will return `true`

```
select tsrange('1990-01-01 00:00:00','infinity') @> tsrange('1990-01-01 00:00:00','2001-10-01 00:00:00')
```